# PROTON: Handshake failed

Tags: node.js, domino-appdev-pack

Get this error on our Domino server log:

PROTON: Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER. [D:\jenkins\workspace\domino-app-dev\fed-protected\grpc\grpc\src\core\tsi\ssl_transport_security.cc:1233]

I am taking the 3CUG courses in google classroom.  When I try to test the code on localhost:3002/api/dql (as per instructions) I get the error above and this returned to the browser:

{"message":"gRPC client error","code":"ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR","cause":{"name":"GrpcError","cause":{"code":2,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{},"flags":0},"details":"Stream removed"}},"stack":"Error\n    at new DominoDbError (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\SourceTree\proton_test\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\src\domino-db-error.js:6:16)\n    at wrapError (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\SourceTree\proton_test\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\src\requests\grpc\utils\grpc-helpers.js:157:10)\n    at C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\SourceTree\proton_test\node_modules\@domino\domino-db\src\requests\grpc\utils\bulk-document.js:210:18\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\SourceTree\proton_test\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1210:9)\n    at InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\SourceTree\proton_test\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:568:42)\n    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\SourceTree\proton_test\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:618:8)\n    at callback (C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\SourceTree\proton_test\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:847:24)"}

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This ususally is a problem with the server config missing the secure flag like so, please check if you have set the flag and import the certificates correctly:

```
const serverConfig = {
    hostName: config.protonHostName, // DNS (!) Host name of your server
    connection: {
        port: config.protonHostPort, // Proton port on your server
        secure: true,
    },
    credentials: {
        rootCertificate,
        clientCertificate,
        clientKey
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is related to lection 404 of the course, you have to turn off SSL for the proton task.

If you're using AppDevPack 1.0.6 or higher you can do this in the `adpconfig.nsf` file.

SSL will be configured in chapter 5.

For turning off ssl for the proton task open adpconfig.nsf.
Then open the configuration document for your server.
[image]

Double click into the document to edit. Uncheck ssl and click save & exit.
After that a prompt asks to restart proton click yes and wait for the proton task to be restarted.
[image: Edit proton config]

Comment: From Review: Could you also please show us how it is done in adpconfig.nsf ?